# Usage of f.collection_select in a has_many :through relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, many-to-many, has-many-through, join

Let me explain my problem,

what I'm trying to do is displaying a dropdown list of teams (one of my models) of which the current user is a member, to allow him to select which of his teams he would like to join a tournament (another model). Here's what I was thinking of doing (and failed doing so):

in the show view of a selected tournament

```
  <%= form_for @new_team, :url => join_tournament_path do |f| %>
      <%= f.collection_select :team_id, current_user.user_teams, team ids of user teams?, user teams names parameter i guess, include_blank: true %>
      <%= f.submit %>
      <% end %>
```

show action in the controller

```
def show
    @tournament = Tournament.find(params[:id])
    @new_team = @tournament.teams_in_tournaments.build
end
```

I'd like the form to send the the tournaments id along with the team id of the team selected by the user to my custom "join" controller action which would save the whole thing.

Hopefully someone could point me in a direction of a solution, because I think I don't really understand how the f.collection_select works (and the documentation wasn't really helpful in my case)

(excuse my english by the way)

EDIT:

My models and relationships:

Team:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_teams
  has_many :users, :through => :user_teams

  has_many :teams_in_tournaments
  has_many :tournaments, :through => :teams_in_tournaments

  belongs_to :team_leader, class_name: "User"
end
```

User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :user_teams
  has_many :teams, :through => :user_teams

end
```

Tournament:

```
class Tournament < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :teams_in_tournaments
  has_many :teams, :through => :teams_in_tournaments
  belongs_to :organizer, class_name: "User"
end
```

UserTeam:

```
class UserTeam < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :team
  validates :team_id, :uniqueness => { :scope => :user_id }
end
```

TeamsInTournament:

```
class TeamsInTournament < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tournament
  belongs_to :team
  validates :team_id, :uniqueness => { :scope => :tournament_id }
end
```

Comment: Can you please post relationship between models?

Comment: Already posted :)

Answer (score 0):

You are halfway there, the only missing thing is to add id's and names of the objects you want outputted in the `<option>` elements

In your case it would be something like this:

```
 <%= form_for @new_team, :url => join_tournament_path do |f| %>
      <%= f.collection_select :team_id, current_user.user_teams, :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
      <%= f.submit %>
      <% end %>
```

Comment: I get a 'undefined method `name' for #<UserTeam:0x007f84bb2921f0>' error. I'm guessing that's because "name" is a property of the Team model, and not the user_teams model - accessing those is my whole problem as I understand it